# What is the recommended way to remove fields from django-models without downtime?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

My team and I work on a shared django repository on a product which requires 99.99+% uptime.

I want to remove a few fields from a frequently used model. Say my model is defined as follows, and I want to remove field2.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
```

Unfortunately this is accompanied by a migration, which if performed, will cause a downtime during deployments because the old servers still reference the non-existent fields in queries, like the ones below.

```
    new_model = MyModel()
    new_model.save()
```

or

```
    MyModel.objects.all()
```

I can't get away without creating a migration because I work on a shared repository, and django will force the new migration on the next developer to make changes to the repo after me.

Is there a recommended way of removing fields from models in django ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to remove fields while avoiding downtime is to remove the fields in multiple steps with deployments done on each step:

1. Remove all usages of the field
2. Make field nullable (null=True) and apply migrations
3. Remove field from the model (without applying migrations)
4. Apply migrations for field removal in step 3